# Ruby on Rails AJAX form to External API

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms

I am trying to set up a form on rails so that after submission, a new partial, with a new form will asynchronously render in the place of the old form.

When our API is being used, our controller calls class methods from our API model, sending params to either our development URI or production URI depending on the environment.

As it stands now, this is how things look:

The sign-up form is here:

```
= form_for "user", url: register_path, remote: true, :authenticity_token => true, :remote => :true, :method => :post do |f|
    = f.text_field :email, required: true
    = f.password_field :password, required: true
    = f.button "Sign Up", :type => "submit"
```

The controller is gathering the data, sending it to our register user method which looks like this:

```
def register_new_user(referral_code = nil)
  response = self.class.post('/user/register',
    :body => {
      :email => @user[:email],
      :pass => @user[:password],
      :device_origin => "web"
    }.to_json
  )

  return response
end
```

The response will contain a JSON object, with a user or an error message. Is there a way for me to then asynchronously have my error messages appear or fadeOut() my old form and fadeIn() my new one?

Thank you! Been grinding on this for hours :'(

Comment: I clicked the up arrow. It says it wont display until I have 15  reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the ERB file where you have your form, you'll want to add an AJAX listener. You can then fire off some jQuery/Javascript and have it do something on Success and on Error.

You're going to need to give your form an ID so the listener knows what to listen to:

`= form_for "user", url: register_path, remote: true, id: 'id-of-form' ...`

**ERB File:**

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('ajax:success', '#id-of-form', function(event, response) {
      var email = response.body.email
      $('#user-email').html(email)
      // Just an example, not sure what your response looks like
    });

    $(document).on('ajax:error', '#id-of-form', function(event, response) {
      $('#error').html(response.error).hide().fadeIn('slow')
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

You might also want to be a little more specific in your controller on how to respond:

```
def register_new_user(referral_code = nil)
  response = self.class.post('/user/register',
      :body => {
        :email => @user[:email],
        :pass => @user[:password],
        :device_origin => "web"
      }.to_json
  )

  # I'm assuming this is in your controller and the method for register_path?

  if response.ok?
    render json: { body: response }, status: 200
  else
    render json: { error: 'Something went wrong' }, status: 400
  end
end
```